# Represent relation between services in SOAF

Tags: foaf, rdf-xml

I have some problem about SOAF; service of a friend (extension of FOAF).

I want to create a SOAF file like this:

```xml
<foaf:knows>
  <soaf:Connection>
    <soaf:established>December 1 s t 2008</soaf:established>
    <soaf:discontinued>December 21 s t 2008</soaf:discontinued>
    <soaf:active>false</soaf:active>
    <soaf:connectiontype>Cont inuous</soaf:connectiontype>
    <soaf:uses>
      <soaf:Service>
        <foaf:name>SOAFReporter</foaf:name>
        . . .
      </soaf:Service>
    </soaf:uses>
  </soaf:Connection>
</foaf:knows>
```

In this file, `soaf:uses` represents the relation between person and services.
In SOAF model, we can represent also the relation between services "services uses services".

I want in my new SOAF file to represent this relation, but I don't know how and I don't find any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent the relation Service A uses Service B like this:

```
<soaf:Service>
    <foaf:name>Service A</foaf:name>
    <foaf:knows>
        <soaf:Connection>
            <soaf:established>December 1 st 2008</soaf:established>
            <soaf:discontinued>December 21 st 2008</soaf:discontinued>
            <soaf:active>false</soaf:active>
            <soaf:connectiontype>Continuous</soaf:connectiontype>
            <soaf:uses>
                <soaf:Service>
                    <foaf:name>Service B</foaf:name>
                    . . .
                </soaf:Service>
            </soaf:uses>
        </soaf:Connection>
    </foaf:knows>
</soaf:Service>
```

Of course, you can also add several connection objects (these encapsulate the actual relation) in the knows relation.